# Как убрать повторяющиеся значения из столбца с разделенными запятой подстроками?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В таблице, значения столбца представлены строками:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a':['female, female, female, female, male, female', 'female, male, female, female', 'female, female, female', 'male, male, male']})

       a
0   female, female, female, female, male, female
1   female, male, female, female
2   female, female, female
3   male, male, male
```

Моё решение с использованием метода `set()`:

```
f = lambda x: [set(y) for y in x.split('; ')]
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(f)
```

Даёт следующий результат:

```
      a                                              b
0   female, female, female, female, male, female    [{m, , e, ,, a, f, l}]
1   female, male, female, female                    [{m, , e, ,, a, f, l}]
2   female, female, female                          [{m, , e, ,, a, f, l}]
3   male, male, male                                [{m, , e, ,, a, l}]
```

А нужно:

```
     a                                               b
0   female, female, female, female, male, female    female, male
1   female, male, female, female                    female, male
2   female, female, female                          female
3   male, male, male                                male
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
df["res"] = [", ".join(set(x.split(", "))) for x in df["a"]]
```

Вариант 2:

```
df["res"] = df["a"].str.split(", ").apply(lambda x: ", ".join(set(x)))
```

Вариант 3:

```
df["res"] = df["a"].str.split(", ").explode().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(set(x)))
```

Результат:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
                                              a           res
0  female, female, female, female, male, female  male, female
1                  female, male, female, female  male, female
2                        female, female, female        female
3                              male, male, male          male
```